# Permissions not being picked up by setup wizard

Tags: magento2, permissions

In reference to this guide:

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

I have followed the guide to install Magento2 into a RHEL 7.2 server word-for-word, however, have not managed to get past the permissions check within the setup wizard.

As per the screenshot below, the permissions as far as I can see, are set correctly and the directories are writable by the Apache user, however, the check just fails.

**I have run a further test by temporarily changing the permissions on one folder to 777, however, this also has no effect and still shows up as failed,** so I can't help thinking there's something I've missed. I've spent 2-3 hours on this already so have finally given up.

Please see the below screenshot as a reference to my setup:

[image: Permissions issue]

Comment: The problem I see is ownership, not permissions. In your system, everything is owned by `apache:apache` but ownership should be `<magento file system owner>:apache`. Start [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#mage-owner-create-user) for information.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've changed this now so that the user 'magento' which is a member of the 'apache' group is the owner, however I'm still getting this error. Any other ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you run the command as a user with root privileges? Did the command return any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 Need to set Right Directorys and files permission

Directory 775

```
 <magento root directory>$ find -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

File  664

```
 <magento root directory>$  find -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Owner Permission to Webserver

centoos:

```
 chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
```

ubuntu:

```
 chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: As shown in the screenshot, the permissions are set to rwxrwxr-x which equates to 775 for the first command.

Comment: yes ,   rwxrwxr-x  equals to 775   for reference  http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: This isn't correct for Magento versions 2.0.6 and later. Instead, try the following command from the Magento root directory: `cd /var/www/html/magento2 && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && sudo chown -R :apache . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento`